# req.session is undefined in POST requests - SailsJS

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

this is my current controller and the result of the logs is the problem.

```
log = console.log.bind(console)

module.exports = 

    test: (req, res) ->
        res.ok()

    current: (req, res) ->  // GET app.com/accounts/current
        log 1, req.session  // 1, Object Session

    login: (req, res) -> // POST app.com/accounts/login
        log 2, req.session // 2, undefined
```

Why is this happening?

I'm using `io.socket.get & io.socket.post` on the client to send these requests

session config

```
module.exports.session = 
    secret: 'bb8775b377f1e8e198b864f8fdacbb9e'
```

I also noticed that response functions such as `res.forbidden & res.ok` etc were also absent, maybe its more sensible to assume that for some reason the whole request is malformed. so if you're having any trouble with that, try my answer, it may help you

Comment: because the session isn't being sent with the login post request? maybe the middleware handling sessions isn't touching post requests? who knows. not enough information.

Comment: @KevinB yes, but why wouldn't it be? it does with GET

Comment: Because the client didn't send it? you have provided no proof that the client has sent the session information with the request.

Comment: @KevinB but it should, you're not funny

Comment: Right no there's no way of knowing whether the problem is with this code, or the code that is sending the request. That has to be determined **first**. start with the source of information, the client.

Comment: I told you in question im using `io.socket.get` & `io.socket.post` now it automatically works properly with get, but not POST, io.socket.?

Comment: @KevinB so thats why i'm asking on here because io.socket is not my code so how would i know

Comment: You could try using a different client to get/post to the server to see if it behaves the same way

Comment: @KevinB ill try postman now

Comment: Theoretically, it should behave the same way, assuming you send the same headers with postman that io.socket.* is.

Comment: @kevinB it works with postman, so must be sails client code, this is what i'm saying

Comment: What type of session store are you using?

Comment: @KevinB default i've added my session config to Q

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94854/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-iconnor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution i found to this was to switch out `io.socket.post` to

```
io.socket.request({url: '/accounts/login', method: 'POST'});
```

Worked like a charm